# Select the body of a stored procedure in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I would like to apply a hash function to a stored procedure in Teradata, but I haven't found the table/view in the catalog where the definition (the content, the body) of the stored procedure is.

Comment: I think the only way to get the DDL for a procedure is to use the `SHOW PROCEDURE` command.

Comment: select CreateText from DBC.TVM where tablekind='P';